# renderMarkdown in shiny vs. "smart" quotes

Tags: r, shiny, markdown, shiny-server

Good morning,

I wonder whether anyone using shiny and renderMarkdown has figured out a way to avoid crashes when the file contains "smart" quotes, as produced e.g. by MS Word, MS Outlook etc. An example is “, which can be generated by typing ALT+0147.

The background is that we have a couple of Markdown files, which are then read into an shiny app. When copy-pasting a text written in Word, Word's auto-correction feature will, by default, replace all quotes etc. with "smart" quotes like the one above(*). When reading in a file that contains such characters in shiny, the software inevitably crashes. When running the shiny application locally on my (Windows) machine, the renderer.option "smartypants" prevents the crash, e.g.:

```
renderMarkdown(filename, renderer.options = "smartypants")
```

However, shiny server - which is Unix-based - still crashes as the file is read in. If the file is long, finding and replacing all such characters is a bit of a pain, so we're looking for an automated solution.

Any ideas?

Thanks, Philipp

(*) I am aware that I can turn off this feature in Word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is to read in the file yourself, use `sub` to regex out the smart quotes (use `\x93` and `\x94`), then change your call to `renderMarkdown(text=subbed_text, renderer.options = "smartypants")`